# Insert in table using Joins and Where

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, insert

I have 2 tables. `expermiment_list` contains the list of experiments and `expermiment_MCQ` contains several questions for that experiment.

For example: ChemistryLab01 stored in `expermiment_list` may have many questions stored in`expermiment_MCQ`

I am able to create new experiment using this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `expermiment_list` (`exp_name`,`exp_duedate`) VALUES
 ('ChemistryLab01','2015/12/12'),
 ('ChemistryLab02','2016/11/11');
```

In this above case, ChemistryLab01 gets exp_id = 1 and ChemistryLab02 gets exp_id = 2. **Show how can I add/insert** questions to `expermiment_MCQ` where exp_id = 1. **Here is my psedue-SQL**:

```
INSERT INTO `expermiment_MCQ` (`exp_question`,`exp_option1`,`exp_option2`,`exp_option3`,
    `exp_option4`,`correct_answer`) VALUES ('Whats your instructor's name?','Adam','Ben','Chris','David',
'Chris') where expermiment_list.exp_id = expermiment_MCQ.exp_id and expermiment_MCQ.exp_id = 1;
```

Two Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `expermiment_list` (
  `exp_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exp_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `exp_duedate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exp_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `expermiment_MCQ` (
  `exp_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exp_question` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  `exp_option1` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `exp_option2` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `exp_option3` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `exp_option4` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `correct_answer` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
);
```

Comment: Look into Foreign keys,transactions and LAST_INSERT_ID

Comment: expermiment? really?

Answer (score 0):

Your psuedo-sql is mostly correct, although the where statement is out of place. Just insert the id directly into the table like you are the other columns:

```
INSERT INTO expermiment_MCQ(
    exp_id,
    exp_question ,
    exp_option1 , 
    exp_option2 , 
    exp_option3 ,
    exp_option4 , 
    correct_answer) 
VALUES (
    1,
    'Whats your instructor''s name?' ,
    'Adam', 
    'Ben', 
    'Chris',
    'David',
    'Chris')
```

As a general tip though, I'd suggest breaking your answers out into another table. When you end up with option1, option2 and so on, you'll need to change your schema to handle option5 +.

I would go for something along the lines of:

```
exp_id | option_num | option | is_correct 
1      | 1          | Adam   | N
1      | 2          | Chris  | Y
1      | 3          | David  | N
```